# Range reference in excel

Tags: excel-formula, reference

I'm in a little bit problem. Actually I am writing a formula in which I can't reference a cell like "B1" or "C9". I will generate a number which will be my column number and my row number is 3 to 9. Now I want a formula like vba cells(3,5):cells(9,5) in replacement of E5:E9. Is there any in excel without any vba?

Thanks guyz!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's ​possible without `INDIRECT` or `OFFSET`

This should work using `INDIRECT`:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row_number1,column_number1)&":"&ADDRESS(row_number2,column_number2))`